# Can a fact rely on an inference?

Tags: argumentation

A syllogism with two facts as premises leads to a deduced *fact*:

> Premise 1: The sky is above my head (*fact*)
>
> Premise 2: I look up and I see blue (*fact*)
>
> Conclusion: The sky is blue (deduced *fact*)

But does a syllogism with one fact and one inference as premises also lead to a deduced *fact*?

> Premise 1: Fred took action `A` (*fact*)
>
> Premise 2: The man we are looking for would not take action A (*inferred* because of the *fact* `A` runs counter to the aims of the man we are looking for)
>
> Conclusion: Fred is not the the man we are looking for (is this a deduced *fact* or an *inference* ?)

Comment: We can call a *statement* a "linguistic fact", but basically a *fact* is a piece of reality  and a statement is a piece of language. A statement can express/describe/denote a fact.

Comment: An argument is a linguistic objects, made of one or more *premises* (that are statements) and one *conclusion* (a statement).

Comment: Being a fact does not depend on the form of deduction used to establish it, although to be an *empirical* fact its deduction would have to contain at least one empirical premise. Logical or mathematical facts (like 2+2=4) can be established without that. But what matters is only that the thing is true, not how one happened to derive it, which can be much more convoluted than simple syllogisms.

Comment: We can say that we have found the truthfulness of a statement regarding a fact because we have correctly inferred the statement expressing that fact from true premises, like e.g. the fact that Socrates is mortal when we derive the corresponding statement from the premises : "Soctares is a man" and "All men are mortals".